# Secure SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to know .

I am trying to make my db private. is it possible.

How to use `context.MODE_PRIVATE` in SQLite DB.

I want to make my db private other app should not access that db.

Comment: Your application's files are sandboxed from others. Your Database's content will not be accessible to other applications unless you make it so. The only way for other apps to see your files without your permission/outside of the ways you specify is if the user has root privileges (in which case all bets are off unless your data is encrypted).

Comment: according tu your view there is nothing context.MODE_PRIVATE in sqlite right?

Comment: Not that I know of. `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` is used for file creation, but database creation is normally done by your implementation of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. I have not seen any way to specify any file creation mode for this (but that's ok, `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` is the default anyway). In any event, other apps should not be able to interact with your database unless you have (a) an exported `ContentProvider` and (b) have published the URIs, column names, etc. that other apps could use to query data.

Comment: If your concern is about malicious parties reading the raw file, you should do as Garry suggests and use encryption.

Answer (score 0):

To protect your database, you have to create your database inside `cache` memory of an Application. And android by default do this thing except you provide an `external storage path` to save your database.